# Override the customer account creation email template in magento2

Tags: magento2, customer, overrides, email-templates

How can I override the core email template of customer account creation in magento2 please give solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can override using theme by below way,

```
app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{themename}/Magento_Customer/email/account_new.html
```

Clear cache.
**Run php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy** command

Comment: Why i want static content deploy comment?i just changed the mail template right i didn't change anything in css and xml whether it must?

Comment: After deploy your new html file will move to your theme magento_customer module and get your changes instead of core customer.

Comment: ok thanks Rajesh i checked now working fine i got new template